# Python pandas importing error

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to import the pandas library I get this error.  I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it.  I tried upgrading it.  I'm using the latest version which I believe is 0.20.  I also tired the default version which is 0.19.  I'm using the latest version of Anaconda, and the latest version of python. I reinstalled Anaconda about 10 time now literally.  I have numpy imported as well which it think is a dependency for it. Any thoughts on this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
        sys.argv = [filename]
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
        exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
      File "C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 10, in <module>
        import pandas as pd
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
        import pandas.core.config_init
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py", line 14, in <module>
        import pandas.core.config as cf
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config.py", line 57, in <module>
        import pandas.compat as compat
    AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'
    >>> runfile('C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
        sys.argv = [filename]
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
        exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
      File "C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 9, in <module>
        import pandas as pd
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
        import pandas.core.config_init
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py", line 14, in <module>
        import pandas.core.config as cf
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config.py", line 57, in <module>
        import pandas.compat as compat
    AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'
    >>> runfile('C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3')
    >>> import pandas.compat as compat
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
        import pandas.core.config_init
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py", line 14, in <module>
    AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'
        import pandas.core.config as cf
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config.py", line 57, in <module>
        import pandas.compat as compat
    AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'
    >>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
        AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    >>> runfile('C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3')
    >>> runfile('C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
        import pandas.compat as compat
    AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'
    >>>     import pandas.core.config as cf
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config.py", line 57, in <module>
        import pandas as pd
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
        import pandas.core.config_init
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py", line 14, in <module>
        sys.argv = [filename]
      File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
        exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
      File "C:/Users/Mason/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 10, in <module>
```